# Why is "select table_name from table_name" valid

Tags: postgresql

This syntax is valid for PostgreSQL:

`select T from table_name as T`

`T` seems to become a CSV list of values from all columns in table_name.  `select T from table_name as T` works, and, for that matter, `select table_name from table_name`.  Where is this syntax documented, and what is the datatype of `T`?

This syntax is not in SQL Server, and (AFAIK) does not exist in any other SQL variant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a table, Postgres creates a [type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtype.html) with the same name in the background. The table is then essentially a "list of that type".

Postgres also allows to reference a complete row as a single "record" - a value built from multiple columns. Those records can be created dynamically through a [row constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS).

Each row in a the result of a SELECT statement is implicitly assigned a TYPE - if the row comes from a single table, it's the table's type. Otherwise it's an anonymous type.

When you use the table name in a place where a column would be allowed it references the full row as a single record. If the table is aliased in the select, the type of that record is still the table's type.

So the statement:

```
select T 
from table_name as T;
```

returns a result with a **single** column which is a record (of the table's type) containing each column of the table as a field. The default output format of a record is a comma separated list of the values enclosed in parentheses.

Assuming `table_name` has three columns `c1`, `c2` and `c3` the following would essentially do the same thing:

```
select row(c1, c2, c3)
from table_name;
```

Note that a record reference can also be used in comparisons, e.g. finding rows that are different between two tables can be done in the following manner

```
select *
from table_one t1
  full outer join table_two t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where t1 <> t2;
```

Comment: Thank you!  I am still processing your responses (this and the one from 4/2016).